# Ayuda con el siguiente Codigo, no se cual podria se el error

Tags: php, mysql

Formulario:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
         <title>Validacion de clientes</title>
        </head>
        <body> 
         tr>
          <h1>Validacion de Clientes</h1>
          <td><label>Codigo del Cliente</label></td>
          <!--<td><input type="text" name="codigo_cliente" placeholder="Codigo" required/></td>-->

          <form action="buscar.php" method="post">
           <td><input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="ingrese Codigo" required/></td>
           <!--<input=type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese codigo">-->
             <td><label><input type="submit" name="name" value="Buscar"> 
          </form>

         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Conexion:

```
 <?php   
     $server = "127.0.0.1";
     $user = "root";
     $pass ="";
     $db = "client_cxp"; 
     $conexion=new mysqli($server,$user,$pass);
     //$conexion = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die ("Error al conectarse");
     //$conexion = mysql_connetc($server,$user,$pass) or die("Error"); 
   ?>
```

Buscar:

```
<?php
     include ("conexion.php");
     $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
     mysqli_select_db ($conexion,$db) or die ("Error de conexion");
     $registros = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM client_cartera WHERE codigo_cliente = '$codigo'") or die ("Error de consulta");

     while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
       {  
          echo $registro['codigo_cliente']." ".$registro['Nom_cliente']." ".$registro['Cartera_vencida']." ".$registro['Cartera_actual']." ".$registro['Cartera_total']." ".$registro['Plazo_credito']." ".$registro['Limit_credito'];
        }  
   ?>
```

Me genera este error:

```
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\buscar.php on line 5 Error de consulta
```

Comment: nosotros tampoco amigo, por favor añade lo que te aparece en pantalla al momento de ejecutarlo

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\buscar.php on line 5
Error de consulta

Comment: corresponderia a la parte de $registros = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM client_cartera WHERE codigo_cliente = '$codigo'") or die ("Error de consulta");

Comment: y si pruebas esto: `mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT......")` es decir en la misma función pasar la var de conexion?

Comment: funciono, arrojo valores del cliente, pero ahora Notice: Undefined index: codigo_cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\buscar.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: Nom_cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\buscar.php on line 9
4016 1881 5898 15 5000

Comment: Asegúrate de que `codigo_cliente` y `Nom_cliente` sean los nombres de los campos en la base de datos

Comment: Gracias, ya pude :) son correcto los datos, 5 BANCO DE FINANZAS - MILLAS 4016 1881 5898 15 5000 son los campos q tinene mi DB, como los introdusco en una tabla? con sus nombres de campo?

Comment: Esta pregunta (con código diferente pero el mismo problema) ya se ha realizado antes y tiene respuesta en el sitio.

Answer (score -3):

El problema es que, en programación procedimental, mysqli_query necesita dos parámetros: el recurso de la conexión, y la consulta en sí. De todos modos, si puedes refactorizar tu código, te sugiero que pases a PDO. Mira en https://eldesvandejose.com/2016/06/16/uso-de-mysql-con-pdo-php-conectar-leer-y-escribir/ y en https://eldesvandejose.com/2017/03/26/uso-de-mysql-con-pdo-php-ii-tratamiento-de-excepciones/

Respecto a lo del undefined index, no has publicado la estructura de tus tablas, pero creo que es ahí donde deberías de mirar.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/132808)

Comment: Si, en eso tienes razón. Sin embargo, en este caso, dado que el contenido relevante es bastante extenso, me pareció fuera de lugar copiarlo todo aquí, y un resumen podría obviar partes importantes. Por eso, en este caso, consideré que los enlaces podrían ser la mejor opción. De todos modos, en otros contextos no dudes que seguiré tu sugerencia. Gracias.